# Using JavaScript to replace &nbsp; in innerText, does not work

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, replace

I'm trying to replace every instance of `&nbsp;` in a number of lines to w (as in the character 'w'.)
The lines are the following:

```
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Monday,&nbsp;Tuesday,&nbsp;Thursday,&nbsp;Friday :  12:00 to 14:00 et  18:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Wednesday :  12:00 to 14:00 et  16:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Saturday :  12:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Sunday,&nbsp;Holidays :  09:00 to 20:30
</li>
```

I've already used the code blow to replace instances of "a" with "e" with success, using `replace(/a/g, 'e')` so I know my code is functional.

My code is as follows:

```
var laHoraireElements = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item horaire-list-item');
    for ( liJ = 0; liJ < laHoraireElements.length; liJ++ ) {
        laHoraireElements[liJ].innerText = laHoraireElements[liJ].innerText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, 'w');
        alert(laHoraireElements[liJ].innerText);
    }
```

The expected outcome would be that instances of `&nbsp;` would be replaced by a 'w', but no instance of `&nbsp;` is modified. What might the reason be?

Comment: I think you need to 'escape' the & and/or the ;

Comment: Could you go through the answers, and respond (with a comment) and/or place votes and/or Accept an answer? That's how this site is supposed to work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&nbsp;` is already rendered as a space in your HTML, therefore there aren't any instances of `&nbsp;` to replace. If you wanted to keep it as is, escaping it will work, allowing you to modify it with a regex replace. As [@barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290233/10445697) mentioned, using innerHTML will do the trick too:

```js
var laHoraireElements = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item horaire-list-item');

for (liJ = 0; liJ < laHoraireElements.length; liJ++) {
  laHoraireElements[liJ].innerHTML = laHoraireElements[liJ].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, 'w');
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
  Monday,&nbsp;Tuesday,&nbsp;Thursday,&nbsp;Friday : 12:00 to 14:00 et 18:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
  Wednesday : 12:00 to 14:00 et 16:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
  Saturday : 12:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
  Sunday,&nbsp;Holidays : 09:00 to 20:30
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Peter B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290301/8289977) answer, I finally understood why I couldn't find the "space" character, even in Notepad++ with "Show All Characters" enabled ! in fact, despite looking like a space, it's a `char(160)` !

And here is how you can replace it directly with a "proper" space :

`element.innerText.replaceAll( String.fromCharCode(160) , ' ' )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` rather than `innerText`. `innerText` contains the rendered text, but entities are part of the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `innerHTML` property, because in `innerText` the `&nbsp;` will have been replaced with a `char(160)` character.

Demo:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item horaire-list-item');

for (var i = 0; i < items[0].innerText.length && i < 20; i++)
{
  console.log(
      i + ": " +
      items[0].innerText.charAt(i) + " | CharCode = " +
      items[0].innerText.charCodeAt(i));
}

for (var liJ = 0; liJ < items.length; liJ++ ) {
    items[liJ].innerHTML = items[liJ].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, 'w');
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Monday,&nbsp;Tuesday,&nbsp;Thursday,&nbsp;Friday :  12:00 to 14:00 et  18:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Wednesday :  12:00 to 14:00 et  16:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Saturday :  12:00 to 20:30
</li>
<li class="list-group-item horaire-list-item">
    Sunday,&nbsp;Holidays :  09:00 to 20:30
</li>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, but `.innerText` indeed replaces `&nbsp;` with `char(160)` not a space ! they look the same, that's why I couldn't replace it !